# Does animation changes the z-index of ul?

Tags: css, html, animation

I am applying a css animation on 4 image to create auto slide. I think the z-index is changed or my approach have a serious problem the layering of the page is messed up, 
here is html code, in this piece of code, one the dives is animated and the other one is not.

```
  <div class="evidence-of-work">
    <div class="website-app">
      <p class= "wrok-title">Coding project</p>
      <a href="./web.html">
        <ul class="autoSlide-items">
            <li class="autoSlide-item">
              <img class="website-screenshot" src="./img/website_screenshot.png" alt="an iphone 6 mobile showing a blond woman in dark blue jacket looking at camera- also some text underneath.">
            </li>
            <li class="autoSlide-item">
              <img src="./img/web-woman-1.png" alt="an iphone 6 mobile showing 2 items of closing placed vertically with the explanation underneath">
            </li>
            <li class="autoSlide-item">
              <img src="./img/web-detail-2png.png" alt="an iphone 6 mobile showing detail of a selected clothing and purchase button">
            </li>
            <li class="autoSlide-item">
              <img src="./img/web-shipping-address-1.png" alt="an iphone 6 mobile shwoing a from for shipping the item to the customer">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </a>
      <p class="work-explanation">An Online shopping website for woman, resposive to the browing device</p>
    </div>
    <div class="daycare-app">
      <p class= "wrok-title">UX desing project</p>
      <a href="./mobile-app.html">
         <img class="daycare-app-screenshot" src="./img/daycare-mobile-screenshot.PNG" alt="">
      </a>
      <p class="work-explanation">A mobile app helping parents to manage communicating with daycare staff easier</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

here is the css:

```
.evidence-of-work{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
.website-app,.daycare-app{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 50px 0px;
}

.daycare-app{
  order: 1;
}

.autoSlide-items{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.autoSlide-item {
  width: 120%;
  margin-top:-2rem !important;
  z-index: 0 !important;
}
.autoSlide-items img{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
.autoSlide-item:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: xfade 32s 0s infinite;
}
.autoSlide-item:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: xfade 32s 8s infinite;
}
.autoSlide-item:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: xfade 32s 16s infinite;
}
.autoSlide-item:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: xfade 32s 24s infinite;
}
@keyframes xfade{
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

.work-explanation{
  text-align: center;
  color:gray;
  font-kerning: 2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.wrok-title{
  text-align: center;
  color:gray;
  }
```

the problem that I am experiencing is that the animated part is covering the text. Plus the text element which its class is called "work-explanation" is supposed to be shown underneath of the sliding photo but it sits right below the upper text element which its class is called work-title. I am really confused can some body give me some hints? 
[image]

Comment: Your CSS animation is not adjusting the `z-index`, but rather the **opacity**. Because your image pulsates from being transparent and opaque, when it is transparent, the text behind it is visible.

Comment: @ObsidianAge: Thanks for the replay, but even when the opacity is 1 the text is still not showing in its proper place which should be below image . why is that ?